# PHP calculating execution time, sometimes return negative value

Tags: php, time, calculus

Calculating execution time using script below:

```
$ php -r "\$tt=microtime();for(\$i=0;\$i<111120;\$i++) \
  echo hash('crc32', microtime()).PHP_EOL;echo 'Time took: ' \
   . (microtime()-\$tt).PHP_EOL;"
```

**Results (multiple):**

```
...
Time took: 0.266269
...
Time took: -0.725037
...
Time took: 0.264577
...
Time took: 0.655573
...
Time took: -0.389367
...
Time took: -0.451503
...
Time took: 0.50867
```

**Why time calculation some times returns negative value?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the second parameter:

```
microtime(true);
```

Otherwise you get a string instead of a real float value which leads to unexpected/wrong results:

> By default, **microtime() returns a string in the form "msec sec"**, where
>   sec is the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
>   Unix epoch (0:00:00 January 1, 1970 GMT), and msec is the number of
>   microseconds that have elapsed since sec expressed in seconds.
>
> — [php.net/microtime](http://php.net/microtime)

(Emphasis mine)

Examples:

```
microtime():     0.93146600 1382611111   (string value)
microtime(true): 1382611111.93146600     (float, printed as a string in this case)
```

Comment: Chrome is warning me about security risks when visiting the site? Did you get this? https://www.google.co.uk/interstitial?url=http://php.net/

Comment: @ScottHelme That's strange. I don't see it, only when clicking on your link.

Comment: Yeah that's the page it takes me to. Are you using Chrome Browser?

Comment: Thanks ComFreek. Works as expected by passing true to microtime(). But it increases execution time a lot than before:

Now results shows: Time took: 2.6399471759796, Time took: 2.586277961731, ...

Comment: @ScottHelme Not at the moment (using IE 10 for testing a site), but I tried it in Chrome. **Edit:** I went directly to the link without Google (though Chrome would also block this). Now, I see it when accessing php.net from Google. I'll remove the link.

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA I doubt that. To which values are you comparing the new values? You cannot compare them to the old ones since the old ones are invalid and wrong!

Comment: @ComFreek It could just be temporary or even a false positive but I thought I'd flag it :-)

Comment: @ScottHelme I cannot even navigate to php.net directly anymore. Chrome immediately blocks it. I hope I didn't get infected :(

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/malware--hacked-sites/puLmvjtK0m8

Comment: @ComFreek I did this:

php -r "\$tt=microtime(true);for(\$i=0;\$i<111120;\$i++) \
      echo hash('crc32', microtime()).PHP_EOL;echo 'Time took: ' \
       . (microtime(true)-\$tt).PHP_EOL;"

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA Again, to which values did you compare These values?